# Python regular expression to identify parentheses pairs in a string; unless the parentheses are in a squared bracket?

Tags: python, regex

I have a strings that look like this:

```
[object]-ABGF-[A-BEC(2)]-LRPG-[object]
ABCDEFGHDGSASDASR-(typ1)-ASDHASDUASIUDHAS-[object]
[object]-RLC(1)-C(2)-GF-[obj]-KSASDASD-[obj3]-ASD-[object]
[object3]-RLC(1)-C(2)-GF-[Hyp]-KSCRSRQCK-[Hyp]-HRCC-[amide]
ABCDEFGHIJK(1)-GHGSHS(2)-ABCDE
ABCDD(1)-ASDASDASD(1)-ASBFIFD
ASDASDASD(1)-ASDASADJASJS(2)-ERASDASD
```

The aim is:
I want to find the strings, where there is parentheses() with numbers, but the numbers aren't in pairs (i.e. there's not two identical numbers in two sets of parentheses), EXCEPT if the parentheses is itself in a square bracket.

For example, the seqs I want to identify from the list above are:

```
[object]-RLC(1)-C(2)-GF-[obj]-KSASDASD-[obj3]-ASD-[object]
[object3]-RLC(1)-C(2)-GF-[Hyp]-KSCRSRQCK-[Hyp]-HRCC-[amide]
ABCDEFGHIJK(1)-GHGSHS(2)-ABCDE
ASDASDASD(1)-ASDASADJASJS(2)-ERASDASD
```

Because each number in parentheses should be in the sequence in pairs, so should have two (1)s in this case, whereas these have a (1) and a (2).

But the following sequence should NOT be returned, because the single parentheses is in a square bracket:

```
[object]-ABGF-[A-BEC(2)]-LRPG-[object] (because it's in a square bracket)
```

I can't hard-code in the numbers, because this should check for, in theory, an infinite number of pairs, e.g. if the sequence was:

```
AVDD(1)-ASDAS(2)-ASDAFJF(3)-ASDAS(1)-ASGGG(2)
```

this should also be returned, because (3) is missing a pair, even though 1 and 2 are paired properly.

But if the sequence was:

```
ASDHD(9)-ASDJAS(9)
```

This would NOT be returned, because that is a pair of parentheses (and the parentheses aren't in brackets)

I wrote this code:

```
circle_pattern = re.compile(r'\(([a-z0-9]+)\)')
if circle_regex:
x_list = ["(" + re.sub("\d", "x", i) + ")" for i in circle_regex]
check_if_even = dict(Counter(circle_regex))
for k,v in check_if_even.items():
       if v % 2 != 0:
                print(row)
```

Which returns:

```
[object]-ABGF-[A-BEC(2)]-LRPG-[object]
ABCDEFGHDGSASDASR-(typ1)-ASDHASDUASIUDHAS-[object]
[object]-RLC(1)-C(2)-GF-[obj]-KSASDASD-[obj3]-ASD-[object]
[object3]-RLC(1)-C(2)-GF-[Hyp]-KSCRSRQCK-[Hyp]-HRCC-[amide]
ABCDEFGHIJK(1)-GHGSHS(2)-ABCDE
ASDASDASD(1)-ASDASADJASJS(2)-ERASDASD
```

But could someone show me how to amend this code, so it does not return the first sequence, because in that case (2) is in squared brackets?

Comment: Should this match? `[object]-ABGF(2)-[A-BEC(2)]-LRPG-[object]`
Should this match? `[object]-ABGF(2)-[A-BEC(2)-DDD(2)]-LRPG-[object]`?

Comment: Did the answer work out?

Answer (score 0):

You might use 2 negative lookaheads to rule out what should not be matched.

```
^(?!.*?\[[^][()]*\([^()]*\))(?!.*?\((\d+)\).*?\1).+
```

The pattern matches

- `^` Start of string
- `(?!` Negative lookahead

  - `.*?\[[^][()]*\([^()]*\)` Match `()` between `[]`
- `)` Close lookahead
- `(?!` Negative lookahead

  - `.*?\((\d+)\).*?\1` Match 2 times the same digit between parenthesis
- `)` Close lookahead
- `.+` Match 1+ times any char

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vGlbZ6/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/Eu3Hkk)

Example

```
import re

regex = r"^(?!.*?\[[^][()]*\([^()]*\))(?!.*?\((\d+)\).*?\1).+"

s = ("[object]-ABGF-[A-BEC(2)]-LRPG-[object]\n"
    "ABCDEFGHDGSASDASR-(typ1)-ASDHASDUASIUDHAS-[object]\n"
    "[object]-RLC(1)-C(2)-GF-[obj]-KSASDASD-[obj3]-ASD-[object]\n"
    "[object3]-RLC(1)-C(2)-GF-[Hyp]-KSCRSRQCK-[Hyp]-HRCC-[amide]\n"
    "ABCDEFGHIJK(1)-GHGSHS(2)-ABCDE\n"
    "ABCDD(1)-ASDASDASD(1)-ASBFIFD\n"
    "ASDASDASD(1)-ASDASADJASJS(2)-ERASDASD")

matches = re.finditer(regex, s, re.MULTILINE)
for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):
    print (match.group())
```

Output

```
ABCDEFGHDGSASDASR-(typ1)-ASDHASDUASIUDHAS-[object]
[object]-RLC(1)-C(2)-GF-[obj]-KSASDASD-[obj3]-ASD-[object]
[object3]-RLC(1)-C(2)-GF-[Hyp]-KSCRSRQCK-[Hyp]-HRCC-[amide]
ABCDEFGHIJK(1)-GHGSHS(2)-ABCDE
ASDASDASD(1)-ASDASADJASJS(2)-ERASDASD
```